# XCTestCase Alamofire with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, swift3, alamofire

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to test my Alamofire function using XCTestCase in Xcode and Swift 3. Currently I tried a lot of times some guides that I found in Stackoverflow regarding this topic but none of them seems to work in my case.

I always end with the following error when performing the test (the error points to the response):

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my **ViewController** code:

```
func performAlamofireRequest(completionHandler: @escaping (Int?) -> Void ) {

    // Header
    var header: String = ""
    header = "http://"

    // URL content
    var string_url: String = ""
    string_url = "localhost:1234"

    // Url
    let url = header + string_url + "/loginuser"

    // Alamofire request
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post).responseJSON { response in

        // Return response code
        completionHandler (200)
    }
}
```

Here is my **testing** code:

```
func testExample() {

    let expectation = self.expectation(description: "fetch posts")

    viewController.performAlamofireRequest() { response in
        XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    self.waitForExpectations(timeout: 5.0, handler: nil)
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Comment: There are few things that you can refactor in your code..

Comment: Could you please tell me so I can write it better? :) Thanks @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃

Comment: according to your details...your request doesn't provides response in JSON format

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it but it seems that it's not working again with the same error. Always nil.